# Is it possible to get the type of the derived class from base class without using template in C++?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have some unrelated classes, that I want all of them to have a pointer of themselves. Naturally I could use template to achieve this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Base {
  // omitted the code to setup the variable
  static T *ptr;
}

class Derived1 : Base<Derived1> {}
class Derived2 : Base<Derived2> {}

// To use:

Derived1 d();
d.ptr->func();
```

My question is, can we achieve this without template, especially with the introduction of so many features in C++20 and 23 (such as Concepts)?

Ideally I'd love to have this:

```cpp
struct Base {
  using Derived = std::directly_derived_type(Base);
  static Derived *ptr;
}

class Derived1 : Base {}
class Derived2 : Base {}
```

In this case if `Base` is ever instantiated without being a base class, compiler should refuse to compile the code because `Derived` can't be resolved.

Comment: You do realize that all instances would share that single program-wide `ptr`? What would that even mean for your the case where two (or more) classes derive from `Base`?

Comment: I think we're looking at an X/Y problem here anyway. What is it that you really want to achieve?

Comment: Is T supposed to share some common interface? But either way, it doesn’t seem possible without templates (maybe w/o CRTP though, eg. using variant). Can you elaborate on the actual use case?

Comment: more hints: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts

Comment: @SebastianRedl In my example, I used `static`, so all `Derived1` would have one `Derived1 *ptr`, but `Derived2` would have `Derived2 *ptr`. It is per class. But it doesn't have to be `static`.

Comment: @alagner, More like a mixin.

Comment: Mixins will usually need to use the CRTP. No, you can't avoid the template here.

Comment: @Bob__ No. I don't need `Base` to ever refer to itself. It's the simplest single inheritance scheme.

Comment: "But it doesn't have to be static". This makes no sense. Static members and non-static members are totally different, and require different answers.

Comment: `I used static, so all Derived1 would have one Derived1 *ptr, but Derived2 would have Derived2 *ptr` then you need to use templates anyways. `Base<Derived1>` and `Base<Derived2>` are created using the same template but are still two distinct types. If you want to have a `static T *ptr` where `T` is either `Derived1` or `Derived2` and `ptr` is not shared between `Derived1` and `Derived2` then the type you inherit from has to be distinct.

Comment: @t.niese I know the types need to be distinct. I'm wonder if C++ has introduced way to dynamically resolve these types in compile-time. Compiler has the information of inheritance, so it can substitute `std::directly_derived_type(Base)` with `D1` when emitting code for `D1`, and `D2` when emitting code for `D2`, just like how template work. I'm asking if we can do without.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I think I'm basically asking if we can do CRTP without template yet. Do you know if the committee has any future plan to change about this area?

Comment: @CrendKing I think you're missing the point that there would be only one `ptr` in total, not one per class.

Comment: May I ask *why* you don't want a templated solution?

Comment: many new features make using tempaltes easier. Sometimes it isnt even immediately apparent that something is a template, but still it is. Especially concepts are specifically for templates. Is there a particular reason you want to avoid the tempalte?

Comment: If you want to keep things simple (for others) then use standard solutions, templates and CRTP are well known so I don't see a problem using them.

Comment: If this is something that is to be either one way or the other during compilation, but never both, how about having an environment variable that says which, and then some macros? `#IF MYENV == 1 static Derived1* ptr; #ELSE ...` (including macros that have either one of the derive classes exist at all)

Comment: @Bob__ No particular reason other than trying to learn alternative way to use the language to keep up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion, there is no template-less approach to CRTP. So I guess I'll stick to the current code.